# How to link orphan files from a source file in generated pdf file

Tags: macros, pdftex, sphinx, texlive-2023

In my documentation project, I am intending to make use of both HTML and pdf documents. As my project has gone quite unwieldy, I have started to store some of the data / information in separate files marked as `:orphan:` so that the `toctree` remains manageable.

In HTML environment, I am able to call in the contents of the `orphan`ed files using links that have been created there and placed as `:ref:` in the calling file. And it has worked quite well so far.

However, in the generated `.pdf` file (using Sphinx `make latexpdf`), the links are not activated (appear as plain text), possibly because the called files are marked as `:orphan:`s? If I include the `:orphan:`ed files in a `:hidden:` `toctree` (in the `index` file), the links to the `:orphan:`s are activated (become *click*able), but they are then **included** in the `.pdf` file's `toctree`.

How do I prevent `orphan` files from appearing in the `.pdf` files `toctree`?

Environment:

```
   Tex Live 2023
   macOS 10.12.6
   Sphinx v7.2.6
   Python 3.9
```

Comment: This does not really sounds like a problem with the latex code. Maybe it would be better suited for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sphinx ?

Comment: No idea of what are you doing really, but If you want easy generation of both HTML and PDF, via LaTeX, with child documents and manageable outlines, my advice is Quarto with RStudio or VSCode.